# C++ - ridiculous long long range

Tags: c++, long-integer

Me and my friend have just encountered a very weird issue with long long range.
So basically, my computer has a 64bit processor but a 32 bit system on it. He has both 32 bit OS and CPU.

First, we printfed `sizeof(long long)`. For both of us that was 8.

Then we did this:

```
long long blah = 1;

printf ("%lld\n", blah<<40);
```

For me this returns 1099511627776 (which is the correct result). For him it is 0.

How is that possible? We both have the same sizeofs.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I compiled and ran it under Win7 with Code Blocks 12.11. He uses Win XP and the same version of CB.

EDIT2: Source codes as requested:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    long long blah = 1;

    printf ("%lld\n", blah<<40);

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf ("%d", sizeof(long long));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say his code is slightly different than yours - for example he did `"%ld"` instead of `"%lld"`. Could you maybe use `cout` instead and tell us the results?

Comment: We both ran the exact same program - I sent him my code.

Comment: Please show us the *complete* program (including any `#include` directives and the full definition of `main`).

Comment: Hmm... I'd still like to know the result of using `cout` - as it may be a issue of `printf` of 32 bit systems.

Comment: Visual Studio 2003 and earlier don't support `%lld`. If you try to use it, you get 0.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the type of the *right* operand of `<<` or `>>` doesn't matter; the type of the result is that of the promoted left operand, which in this case is `long long`.

Comment: @dauphic: Good point -- but does VS support `long long`? szczurcio: What OS and compiler are you and your friend using?

Comment: @KeithThompson The codes + OS and compiler details are now in my question.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, Visual Studio supports `long long`.

Comment: @szczurcio: I don't think Codeblocks comes packaged with any C/C++ compilers.

Comment: Did you send friend the source code or the compiled program? If what you sent was the compiled program how did you compile it? With gcc it's possible for example to compile a program that will only work correctly on a specific processor type.

Comment: I sent him the source code, he compiled it himself.

Comment: @dauphic It does - http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26 - you can download it with MinGW.

Comment: Use `"%zu"` to print a `size_t` value (such as the result of `sizeof`) -- or, for a compiler that doesn't support it, use `"%lu"` and cast to `unsigned long`: `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(long long));`

Comment: @KeithThompson It certainly is a better practice, but could that really matter in this case? The results should still be correct, shoudn't they?

Comment: @szczurcio: It could fail if `int` and `size_t` are of different sizes -- but it would only affect printing the `sizeof`, not `blah<<40`. Try using a format of `"%I64d"; I think some Microsoft systems use that instead of the standard `"%lld"`. (`"%I64d"` will *only* work with Microsoft, so don't use it in general.)

Comment: @KeithThompson a search for codeblocks, xp and lld comes up with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418170/long-long-int-is-interpreted-as-long-int-how-do-i-get-round-this) which seems to make the same recommendation and it seemed to work for that OP.

Comment: Hmm, that would explain, but why is it working for me? Anyway, thank you, I'll tell him to try this when we'll get in contact (time difference).

Comment: I wrote a simple console app using Visual Studio 2005 on Windows XP in which I created two long long variables, assigned a value of 1 to one of them (blah), then shifted that value by 40 and assigned to the second (blah2) using `blah2 = blah<<40;`, then used `printf ()` with `%lld` to print the values of blah, blah2, and blah<<40 `printf (" value, %lld %lld %lld\n", blah, blah2, (blah<<40));` and I got the correct values of 1, 1099511627776, 1099511627776 so I am not sure what your problem is.

Comment: @RichardChambers Precisely, that's what (I think) should happen. But blah<<40 on my friend's system gives 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you and your friends are linking to different versions of the infamous `MSVCRT.DLL` or possibly some other library.

From the Code::Blocks FAQ:

> Q: What Code::Blocks is not?
>
> A: Code::Blocks is not a compiler, nor a linker. Release packages of Code::Blocks may include a compiler suite (MinGW/GCC), if not provided by the target platform already. However, this is provided "as-is" and not developed/maintained by the Code::Blocks development team.

So the statement "I compiled and ran it under Win7 with Code Blocks 12.11" isn't strictly true; you cannot compile with something that isn't a compiler.

Figure out what compiler you two are actually using (see, above: it is not "Code Blocks") and what library.

Answer (score 1):

Could be one of two problems: either the printing system cannot cope with long long or the shift operator does not work over 32 bits.  Try this

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
   union
   {
      long long one;

      // Intel based systems are back to front
      struct {
         long lo;
         long hi;
      } two;
   } xxx;

   xxx.one = 1LL;
   xxx.one = xxx.one << 40;
   printf ("%016llx %08x %08x\n", xxx.one, xxx.two.hi, xxx.two.lo);
   return 0;
}
```

If the first number is all zeros but one of the other two isn't, then it is the printf that cannot cope.  If all the numbers are zeros, then the shift operator isn't defined for 64 bits.