# Printing a value changes the output of the code

Tags: c++, ide

Few hours ago, a competition was held on [CodeForces](http://codeforces.com) , this was one the questions of the competition -

[Problem C](http://codeforces.com/contest/834/problem/C) (You dont *have to* read/solve it to answer the question)

EDIT : Adding the question here as requested, again, one does not necessarily have to read it.

> Slastyona and her loyal dog Pushok are playing a meaningless game that
>   is indeed very interesting.
>
> The game consists of multiple rounds. Its rules are very simple: in
>   each round, a natural number k is chosen. Then, the one who says (or
>   barks) it faster than the other wins the round. After that, the
>   winner's score is multiplied by k2, and the loser's score is
>   multiplied by k. In the beginning of the game, both Slastyona and
>   Pushok have scores equal to one.
>
> Unfortunately, Slastyona had lost her notepad where the history of all
>   n games was recorded. She managed to recall the final results for each
>   games, though, but all of her memories of them are vague. Help
>   Slastyona verify their correctness, or, to put it another way, for
>   each given pair of scores determine whether it was possible for a game
>   to finish with such result or not.
>
> Input In the first string, the number of games n (1 ≤ n ≤ 350000) is
>   given.
>
> Each game is represented by a pair of scores a, b (1 ≤ a, b ≤ 10^9) –
>   the results of Slastyona and Pushok, correspondingly.
>
> Output For each pair of scores, answer "Yes" if it's possible for a
>   game to finish with given score, and "No" otherwise.
>
> You can output each letter in arbitrary case (upper or lower).

So I solved it, and after the competition was over, me and my friends were discussing the problems when they asked me what was my answer coming for the following test case -

1
1 1

I said it was "Yes" on my IDE (Dev-C++ 5.11), (as it was supposed to be)
But when we ran it on ideone, it came out to be "No" !!

I thought there must be a problem with my code only, so i tried debugging it when i came across this problem,

My Code -

```
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

long long int iscube(long long int n)
{
    long long int lo = 0;
    long long int hi = 1000000;
    while(lo < hi)
    {
        long long int mid = (lo+hi)/2;
        if(mid*mid*mid < n)
            lo = mid+1;
        else
            hi = mid;
    }
    return lo;
}

int main()
{
    long long int a,b;
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--)
    {
        scanf("%I64d %I64d",&a,&b);
        long long int c = a*b;
        long long int cb = iscube(c);
        //printf("%lld",cb)
        if(cb*cb*cb == c)
        {
            if(a%cb == 0 && b%cb == 0)
                printf("Yes\n");
            else
                printf("No\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

When i give the input as

```
1  
1 1
```

in the above code, the answer comes out to be "No"
BUT if I **ONLY** uncomment the line above the if statement in the while loop in the main() function,

the answer would be "1 Yes"

(these outputs are the outputs i got when i ran the code on ideone, when running on Dev-C++ 5.11 , i got "Yes" and "1 Yes" as expected)

Now while i was thinking that my my answer of codeforces would be evaluated as WA, After the system test, it came out to be *Accepted*!

Does anyone have any idea on why this issue is arising?

(Also, could someone add the appropriate tags, if any)

Comment: Place the relevant portions of the problem in the question. Links can get stale. Also, admittedly, StackOverflow has a pretty strong bias against online judge sites.

Comment: This is possible a repeat of the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734687/c-ridiculous-long-long-range   You could go there and read all about it.

Comment: @AndyG Added the code, and removes the links,

Comment: @Drt I read the question, and no, i dont think it is repeat of that question

Comment: @HarshitSinghal: You still have not put the relevant portions of the problem in the question. StackOverflow is meant to be self-contained. It's impossible to understand *what* you're trying to solve without following a link right now.

Comment: @AndyG Yes it is completely self-contained, i just put that link in there for reference, one doesnt need to read it at all as am not asking what is correct answer or wrong answer...But still, you probably know more than i do, I've added what was required...i hope you can answer now...

Comment: [`I64d`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx) is not a standard format specifier. ("The I, I32, and I64 length modifier prefixes are Microsoft extensions and are not ANSI-compatible.") I believe that makes the code undefined except in Visual C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo I was using "%lld" but the codeforces website asked not to use that, instead use I64d for some reason...As it turns out, using lld gives "Yes"

Answer (score 4):

Turn up your warnings, you have undefined behavior in your `scanf`:

```
 warning: length modifier 'I64' results in undefined behavior or no effect with 'd' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
        scanf("%I64d %I64d",&a,&b);
```

If you change it to `scanf("%lld %lld",&a,&b);` (C++11), then you'll have defined behavior, however since you're using C++, just use a stream instead:

```
std::cin >> a >> b;
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ndxh5KQMxog9Vwhm)